# How to iterate clicks until the Web element is not visible in Robot framework

Tags: python, selenium, robotframework

I've been trying to Click on a story reader until the Next button is not visible i.e untill the last page in Robot Framework, I am trying out different ways but not getting a good solution. Can anyone help me out.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom keyword like below and use it wherever required.
Below keyword will wait maximum 60 seconds and if it is visible in 5 seconds, then it will proceed further in 5 seconds. And pass the locator as argument, so that it locator can be dynamic.

```
*** Test Cases ***

Do something
Wait_60s_And_Click    ${locator}

*** Keywords ***

Wait_60s_And_Click
    [Arguments]    ${locator}
    Wait Until Element Is Visible    ${locator}    timeout=${Timeout_60s}
    Capture Page Screenshot
    Click Element    ${locator}
```